# I want to manipulate object coming from database to json in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is the data I got after querying multiple join statements in hibernate.

```
[
    [
        "Love Story",
        85565008
    ],
    [
        "Drama",
        46935824
    ],
    [
        "Action",
        39098714
    ],
    [
        "Comedy",
        33348991
    ],
    [
        "Horror",
        16597704
    ],
    [
        "Social Drama",
        7875711
    ],
    [
        "Animated",
        1760884
    ]
]
```

I want the data from above date in following Format in Java.

```
[
    {
        Genre:"Love Story",
       Collection: 85565008
    },
    {
        Genre:" Action",
       Collection: 2452435234
    },
    {
        Genre:"Comedy",
       Collection: 2345245243
    }
]
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Add code for getting raw data from Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with variables Genre and Collection.

```
public class Movie{
public String genre;
public String collection;

public void setGenre(String genre){
    this.genre=genre;
 }
public String getGenre(){
    return genre;
}
public void setCollection(String collection){
    this.collection=collection;
}

public String getCollection(){
    return collection;
}
}
```

then iterate through your list and add them to a list of Movie.

```
   List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i=0;i<arr.lenth;i++){
        m=arr.get(i); // individual lists in the list
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setGenre(m.get(0));
        movie.setCollection(m.get(1));
        movies.add(movie);    
    }
     System.out.print(movies);
```

Comment: What is the datatype of m?

Comment: Tq very much @Sabira